# Custom Login Page with Spring Boot and Vue.js

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, vuejs2, spring-web

I want to use my custom loginpage, made with `Bootstrap-Vue` and the `Vue.js`, with my `spring boot` backend. I'm using `Spring Security`.

This is my custom login form

```html
<b-form @submit="onSubmit" >
  <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup1" label="Username:" label-for="exampleInput1">
    <b-form-input id="exampleInput1" type="username" v-model="form.username" required placeholder="Enter username"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
    <b-form-group id="exampleInputGroup2" label="Password:" label-for="exampleInput2">
      <b-form-input id="exampleInput2" type="password" v-model="form.password" required placeholder="Enter password"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
  <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Login</b-button>
  <b-button type="reset" variant="secondary">Register</b-button>
</b-form>
```

My `SecurityConfig` class looks like

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/app");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}
```

My project is connected to a database, so I can test a login with a user from my database. It already worked with the default loginpage of spring security. My question is how do I use it with a custom form?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I reformatted the code parts and highlighted some keywords like `vuejs`, `spring security` etc